# Microfeed web part / My Site News Feed 2013 customization

Tags: 2013, web-part, newsfeed, mysite

Based on my readings, the microfeed web part is located in

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebContols.MicrofeedWebPart
```

Anyone know where to find the ascx.cs file for this web part control?

I need to re-use the code to place it on another site collection without affecting the original My Site News feed.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a video that does a deep dive on the microfeed - probably just what you're after

http://www.bing.com/videos/watch/video/sharepoint-2013-microfeed-overview/10tg8arkf?cpkey=33acbc08-3b43-4c8e-a874-e9f7c2204380%7C%7C%7C%7C

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)